# How to check whether the input name contains specific value using if loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table with values. some of values ends with specific string so i want to check whether input `name` attribute contains specific string using if loop.

i have tried using below code but it is not working:

```
$("#tabTax tbody tr").each(function () {
    if (this.name.endswith('taxtype')) {
        $(this).replaceWith('<tr id="rowTax' + $(this).find("input[name$='taxtype']").val() + '><td hidden="hidden"></td><td> ' + $(this).find("input[name$='taxtype']").val() + '(' + parseFloat($(this).find("input[name$='Taxperce']").val()) + '%)</td><td><input type="text" name= Bookingtax[' + rowcount + '].TaxAmount  disabled="disabled"  class="form-control chargesinputfield" value=' + ($(this).find("input[name$='Taxperce']").val() * sum / 100).toFixed(2) + '></input></td><td hidden="hidden"><input name=Bookingtax[' + rowcount + '].TaxID id=' + $(this).find("input[name$='TaxID']").val() + ' type="text" class="form-control" value=' + $(this).find("input[name$='TaxID']").val() + ' ></input></td><td hidden="hidden"><input name=Bookingtax[' + rowcount + '].taxtype id=' + $(this).find("input[name$='taxtype']").val() + ' type="text" class="form-control" value=' + $(this).find("input[name$='taxtype']").val() + ' ></input></td><td hidden="hidden"><input name=Bookingtax[' + rowcount + '].Taxperce id=' + $(this).find("input[name$='Taxperce']").val() + ' type="text" class="form-control" value=' + $(this).find("input[name$='Taxperce']").val() + ' ></input></td><td hidden="hidden"><input name=Bookingtax[' + rowcount + '].TaxAmount id=' + $(this).find("input[name$='TaxAmount']").val() + ' type="text" class="form-control" value=' + ($(this).find("input[name$='Taxperce']").val() * sum / 100).toFixed(2) + ' ></input></td></tr>')
        rowcount++;
    } else {
        $("#discountrate").replaceWith('<tr id="discountrate"><td> Discount</td><td hidden="hidden"></td><td><input type="text" name="Discountrate"  id="txtDiscountrate"  class="form-control chargesinputfield" value="' + $("#txtDiscountrate").val() + '"></input></td><td hidden="hidden"><input name=Bookingtax[' + rowcount + '].Taxperce id=' + $(this).find("input[name$='Taxperce']").val() + ' type="text" class="form-control" value=' + $(this).find("input[name$='Taxperce']").val() + ' ></input></td><td hidden="hidden"><input name=Bookingtax[' + rowcount + '].TaxAmount id=' + $(this).find("input[name$='TaxAmount']").val() + ' type="text" class="form-control" value=' + ($(this).find("input[name$='Taxperce']").val() * sum / 100).toFixed(2) + ' ></input></td></tr>')
    }
})
```

I tried with this if `(this.name.endswith('taxtype'))`, but it is not working.

Please help. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Comment: Your argument of the `replaceWith` function is so messy @@

Comment: `<input>` has no closing tag..

Comment: Typo. Its `endsWith` actually not `endswith`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use `$(this).is("[name$=taxtype]")`

This will check if the `name` ends with the string `taxtype` ( `$=` means ends with)

**Demo**

```js
$("#tabTax tr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).is("[name$=taxtype]")) {
    console.log("name ends with taxtype")
    if ($(this).is("[name=taxtype]")) {
      console.log("this only match taxtype")
    }
  } else {
    console.log("name does not ends with taxtype")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabTax">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr name="taxtype"></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr name="somethingtaxtype"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried removing the `$`. It is still displaying same result.. Why is that?

Comment: Did you remove the first or last `$` in `$(this).is("[name$=taxtype]")` ?

Comment: the `$` in name..I tried some expirement with it and I got what it was.. I learned something new.. +1 from me :)

Comment: @ShadowFiend because my example just name is an exact match to taxtype. but if you add somethingtaxtype then it should show something else